# How to write text on UITextView programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to write on a TextView dynamically, actually my app retrieve data from database and need to display it on a UITextView, can any one help me there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

```
textView.text = @"your string of text";
```

where textView is your UITextView object.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answer, i have one other question :` for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
  textView.text = @"String number";
 }`
this loop suppose to display the sentence 100 times, but in my case it's displayed one time, why is that?

Comment: try with: `for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { textView.text += @"String number"; }`

Comment: i don't think that was helpful :) it gives me error : ` error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'struct NSString *' and 'struct NSString *')`

Comment: you're right. try: `for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { textView.text = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:@"String number"] ; }`